# location pathname removing icon at wrong pathway in react

Tags: reactjs

I currently have a project laid out like this:

[image]

I'm trying to make it so that when you click the shopping cart icon and go to the cart, the cart icon disappears. However when I try and write the logic for location.pathname it ends up removing the shopping cart icon on the products page itself like so:

[image]

How do I fix this so that the shopping cart item disappears only when I am actually in the cart section (which I have linked up using react router)?

My Navbar component:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  IconButton,
  Badge,
  MenuItem,
  Menu,
  Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { ShoppingCart } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from "../../assets/commerce.png";
import useStyles from "./styles";

const Navbar = ({ totalItems }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const location = useLocation;

  return (
    <>
      <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar} color="inherit">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography
            component={Link}
            to="/"
            variant="h6"
            className={classes.title}
            color="inherit"
          >
            <img
              src={logo}
              alt="Generic commerce template"
              height="25px"
              className={classes.image}
            />
            Generic Commerce Template
          </Typography>
          <div className={classes.grow} />

          {location.pathname === '/' && (
          <div className={classes.button}>
            <IconButton component={Link} to="/cart" aria-label="Show cart items" color="inherit">
              <Badge badgeContent={totalItems} color="secondary">
                <ShoppingCart />
              </Badge>
            </IconButton>
          </div>
          )}
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Also where I used react router in App JS:

```
return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Navbar totalItems={cart.total_items} />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Products products={products} onAddToCart={handleAddToCart} />
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/cart">
            <Cart cart={cart} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to the useLocation function is missing parentheses:

```
const location = useLocation;

// should be:
const location = useLocation();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this check in the navbar component. The navbar component should take a property like showCartIcon. You can set this property to false on any page you want.